# Does Block Producer`s votes percentage affect their block reward or block generation frequency?

Tags: block-producer

I am curious if TOP 1 Block Producer:

- will be generating blocks more frequent than the others?
- will be gaining more rewards when creating a block than the others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am curious if TOP 1 Block Producer:
>
> - will be generating blocks more frequent than the others?

Nope, they are entitled to generate the same number of blocks, even if it's possible they may miss some due to technical issues.

> - will be gaining more rewards when creating a block than the others?

Sort of: although they'll get the same *block rewards*, they'll get more *vote rewards*.

Dan's explanation [here](https://medium.com/eosio/introducing-eosio-dawn-4-0-f738c552879):

> There are 21 active block producers and any number of standby
>   producers. The top 21 divide up the 0.25% per-block rewards
>   proportional to the number of blocks each one producers. All block
>   producer candidates (including the top 21) also divide up the .75%
>   per-vote rewards budget proportional to the total number of votes they
>   receive. They can claim their share of the per-vote rewards at most
>   once-per-day. In order to claim their share they must qualify for at
>   least 100 tokens/day. Producers candidates who do not qualify for at
>   least 100 tokens/day on a per-vote basis will receive nothing.

[image: diagram of reward distributio]

* note that the 4% allocation for WPS is not yet decided on the mainnet